# Is there any common library that can be used for navigation for both web and mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I have tried "react-navigation" in sample app created by using "create-react-app" command. It's working in mobile but not working for web.
Also tried implementing navigation using "react-router-dom", which is working perfectly for web. But not working for mobile giving ‘Error: Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM’.

[image]

Comment: Why should `react-navigation` not be working on the web? What do you mean by "not working" exactly?

Comment: I can see only navigation bar not the content of the screen which I have designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://reactrouter.com

//this site will help you for Both Native and web thanks

Comment: i used react-router-native but in mobile it's not showing navigation bar with back button